# looking for efficient way to add dynamic columns to pandas df using dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add two new columns to existing pandas data frame. I have implemented it using a python function with multiple if else statement. But i think it's not the best approach, if i can use dictionary or some other approach to achieve the same ?

I am using below code to add new columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {"col_1": [1234567, 45677890, 673214, 6709,98765,'',876543]} )
def func(col_1):
    col_1=str(col_1)

    if col_1=="":
        return "NA",""
    elif col_1[0:3]=='123':
        return "some_text_1 "," other_text_1"
    elif col_1[0:3]=='456':
        return "some_text_2 ","other_text_2"
    elif col_1[0:2]=='67':
        return "some_text_3 ","other_text_3"
    elif col_1[0:1]=='9':
        return "some_text_4 ","other_text_4"
    else:
        return "Other","Other"

df["col_2"],df["col_3"]=zip(*df["col_1"].map(func))
print(df)


        col_1         col_2          col_3
    0   1234567  some_text_1    other_text_1
    1  45677890  some_text_2    other_text_2
    2    673214  some_text_3    other_text_3
    3      6709  some_text_3    other_text_3
    4     98765  some_text_4    other_text_4
    5                      NA               
    6    876543         Other          Other
```

So what i am trying to find out here as i have multiple if and else statements what would be best way to achieve the same. Should i use dictionary or any other approach, any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is probably slow because it is not vectorized.  Here is an alternative method:

```
temp = df['col_1'].astype(str)
df = df.assign(col_2='Other', col_3='Other')
df.loc[temp.str[0] == '9', ['col_2', 'col_3']] = ('some_text_4 ', 'other_text_4')
df.loc[temp.str[0:2] == '67', ['col_2', 'col_3']] = ('some_text_3 ', 'other_text_3')
df.loc[temp.str[0:3] == '456', ['col_2', 'col_3']] = ('some_text_2 ', 'other_text_2')
df.loc[temp.str[0:3] == '123', ['col_2', 'col_3']] = ('some_text_1 ', 'other_text_1')
df.loc[temp == "", ['col_2', 'col_3']] = ("NA", "")
>>> df
      col_1         col_2         col_3
0   1234567  some_text_1   other_text_1
1  45677890  some_text_2   other_text_2
2    673214  some_text_3   other_text_3
3      6709  some_text_3   other_text_3
4     98765  some_text_4   other_text_4
5                      NA              
6    876543         Other         Other
```

The idea is that you are reversing the order of your if/else statements so that you execute the least important first.  Subsequent rules take precedence and could overwrite the rules above it.

Comment: Is their a way to implement the same using dictionaries ?

Comment: Also your solution is not working what is temp here ? is it col_1 value?

Comment: Oops.  `temp = df['col_1'].astype(str)`.

Comment: thanks Alexander, it significantly improves the performance, do you also see any further improvements may be by using dictionaries ?

Comment: Not in this case.  Perhaps if all the keys had the same length.  What makes it unusual here is that the size of your string slice (e.g. 1-3) characters depends on its contents and order.

Comment: Also can you just brief me on this vecotrized approach ? as on small data it seems slow then multiple if else

Comment: @user07 Your code may actually be faster depending on the size of your dataset.  In general, it is slower to map the same function over every value in a series, such as each row, compared to performing an equivalent operation using numpy vectorization. See the attached link for more information:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/whatisnumpy.html